# Highlight all occurrences in margin bar in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have seen many variations of this question, but not the version I am looking for - sorry for reposting if I might have missed one though.

I am using Visual Studio 2015, and I love the preview Scrollbar feature in the margin. In earlier VS versions I used to use RockMargin, but the built-in VS one is much better in my opinion, and has the extra useful feature of previewing code when you hover over it. Like so:

[image]

However, I also live and die by the highlighting feature that highlights all occurrences of a selected variable/function *in the scroll bar*. RockMargin had this, but I can't find any extension for the VS2015 native version that does this. Does this exist?

Comment: Good question.  I tried E-Riz's solution, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TrungKienPhan.WordHighlight-18643) seems to be what you're looking for. It adds markers in the right margin for matches to the selected "word."

The VS 2017 version of the same extension is [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TrungKienPhan.WordHighlight-18439).